# Best way to handle SQL Server fulltext index updates

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a fulltext index which doesn't need to be immediately up-to-date, I'd like to spare myself the I/O (when I do bulk updates, I see a ton of I/O related to the index) and do the index updates during low usage times (nightly, perhaps even weekly).  It seems there are two ways to go about this:

1. Turn off change tracking (SET CHANGE_TRACKING OFF) and add a timestamp field to the indexed table, so that you can run `alter fulltext index on <table> start INCREMENTAL population`, or
2. Enable change tracking, but set it to MANUAL, so that you can run `alter fulltext index on <table> start UPDATE population` when you need it updated.

Is there a preferred method?  I couldn't tell from [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188359.aspx) if there was a performance benefit one way or the other.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind waiting for a full poulation, I'd choose your first option.
The second option works fine, but it leaves the index fragmented  and you will have evenctually to do a full population or you will have performance problems.